# Mongodb $addFields does not outputs the data if null

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

i am struggling with an annoying problem. I am using aggregation in a query and i need to join some collections and the output has to be an object. This is my code...

```
usersModel.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { _id: ObjectId(req.params.id) }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "agents",
            as: "agent",
            let: { "idAgent": "$agent" }, //$agent can be null
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        $expr: {
                            $eq: ['$_id', "$$idAgent"] 
                        },
                    }
                }
            ],
        }
    },
    { $unwind: { path: '$agent', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },
    {
        $addFields: {
            agent: "$agent", //If $agent is null, it does not output the field agent...
        }
    }

])
```

If in the last Stage, the field $agent is null, $addFields does not output the field.
There is any other approach to do it? i need just agent field as an object after lookup. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add an [**`$ifNull`**](https://docs.huihoo.com/mongodb/3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull.html) condition with [**`$addFields`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/)

```
{
  "$addFields": {
    "agent": { "$ifNull": ["$agent", {}] }
  }
}
```